# Run Java EE Sample Projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, glassfish-3, sample

I want to run the sample Java EE projects that come with glassfish from within Eclipse. The server is all set up but Im having difficulty importing the projects from the glassfish directory.
Any guidance would be appreciated.

GF

Comment: why don't you detail the difficulties you're running into?

Comment: @Mat, I cannot import the projects in their current format i.e. Directories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a WAR or EAR file in Eclipse and deploy it to Glassfish.  That should do it.